# What is the best way to version DACPACs within Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-pipelines, versioning, dacpac

I currently use Azure DevOps and I want to know if there is a way to see which DACPAC version I am using, via Azure DevOps Pipelines. If this isn't an option, any suggested alternatives?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you trying to version the dacpac when generating the dacpac, or view the version when generating it? Or view the version of a created dacpac?

Comment: Hi - I am trying to version the dacpac when generating the dacpac, and subsequently, view the version after generation.

Comment: Thank you, this is starting to become clearer. For step one, I have not used the MSBuild Arguments before, is that an arbitrary version number you put in there? While running the pipeline, I want the pipeline to generate the new version number for me, as there may be a revision for every build. This will then create a new artifact, and that artifact should be versioned.

Comment: Using the Azure SQL Publish task, I can see where to specify the deployment package information but still no options on how to generate a version.

Comment: Which task do you use to generate the dacpac in azure devops pipeline?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to version DACPACs within Azure DevOps?

To specify version when building SQL Server Database project, you can add argument:

[image]

> To view the version when generating it, you can add this script to your `ProjectName.sqlproj` file:

```
  <Target Name="OutputDacVersion" AfterTargets="build">
    <Message Text="The newly generated dacpac's version is: $(DacVersion)." Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

> To view the version of an existing `xx.dacpac` file:

Since the `xx.dacpac` file is actually a `xx.zip` file, we can rename it and then extract it. The `DacMetadata.xml` within it contains the version info of the .dacpac. In Devops, we can add steps below to get the version:

1.CMD task: `copy MyDatabase.dacpac OneCopy.zip`

2.Extract Files task:

[image]

3.CMD task: `call xpath.bat  "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\FolderThatHostCopy\DacMetadata.xml" "//Version"`

**Note:** Create a [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) file in your root directory of repo to parse the xml file before running the pipeline.